# using RXTX to communicate with rs232 /how to get the appname?

Tags: java, port, rxtx

I am using the RXTX to communication with the serial port.

[This is my project:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGXWZ.png)

In open method I give a appname which is "Test"

```
public void connect(String portName) throws Exception {  
        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);  

        if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {  
            System.out.println("port in use");  
        } else {  

            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) portIdentifier.open("Test", 2000); 


            serialPort.setSerialPortParams( 9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_ODD);  


            CommPortSender.setWriterStream(serialPort.getOutputStream());  


            new CommPortReceiver(serialPort.getInputStream()).start();  
          //  System.out.println(serialPort.get);
        }  
    }
```

this is the detail of  parameters:

```
public CommPort open(java.lang.String appname,int timeout)
          throws PortInUseException
```

appname - Name of application making this call. This name will become the owner of the port. Useful when resolving ownership contention.

timeout - Time in milliseconds to block waiting for port open.

How can I get the appname which I gived at open method in
the following funtion:

```
private void onMessage() { 
    if (tail!=0) {         
        String message = getMessage(buffer, tail);  
        System.out.println("received message: " + message);  

        tail = 0;  
    }  
}
```

I am searched for google ,but have no idea how to describe this problem. Please help.
Thanks in advance and please forgive my poor English.

Comment: Please do not post images of your code but the actual code. This makes it way easier to understand and reproduce your problem and actually help you.

Comment: thank you Ben I have changed my question